# Setting up Rode Microphone with a Steinberg UR22 mk2 USB Audio Interface with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, microphone

I am looking for Documentation on how to setup a Rode Microphone with a Steinberg UR22 mk2 USB Audio Interface with Ubuntu 16.04.

Ubuntu Recognizes the Steinberg UR22 as a device and I unmuted it under Alsamixer. I was able to push Audio through the Ur22 on my laptop but The problem is I am getting no output from the Rode Microphone.

If someone could direct me on how to setup this device it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Install pulseaudio volume control  :

`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

Run it and select your device as default in "input device" tab by clicking corresponding  green button.

If problem, look in "configuration" tab  and use  profile for your device.

If no luck, go to Alsamixer as you did,    press F4 key  to display capture controls :
 Try to increase capture  volume (up/down key) or select capture source by pressing space key on the correct fader.